# Move projects in Git to Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have some projects in My Git Repository. I would like to move all that to Gerrit. I am not mentioning about importing projects one by one from git and pushing it to Gerrit as it might take a lot of time as the number of projects in Git is large. Or in other words I can say like I would like to convert the local git repository to the git repo of my Gerrit so that I can get all the existing projects in local Git in Gerrit. For this I gave the Location of Git repositories during gerrit initialization as my local Git Repository and tried but I didnt get the result which I was looking for. Though All-Projects.git came there, in the Gerrit UI other projects in the local Git repositories were not listed. Is there anyway to do this? It would be greatly helpful if someone could help me to solve this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to move existing repositorys to gerrit. Don't forget, always create a new project with this repository. Mandatory. You can automate it via their API. It's not difficult to create a project via API.

Options you have then:

1. copy the old .git folder to the place of the newly from gerrit created one. What basically asked for.
2. import the old git repository into gerrit while not having direct access to the file system.

   `\# In an existing repository
   git remote rm origin
   git remote add origin ssh://your-gerrit-instance:29418/folder/repository
   git push --tags origin
   git push --all origin`

I know that the 2nd one is not what you ask for, but if you have a dozen of git repositories and automate it anyway, that would be an option, too.

I would also suggest to reindex in the end. I am not 100% sure if it is needed in this case.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gerrit stop
java -jar /var/gerrit/review/bin/gerrit.war reindex -d /var/gerrit/review
sudo /etc/init.d/gerrit start
```

Comment: I copied my .git folder in git repo into the git repo locaiton of gerrit. But I am not able to import the project into Eclipse. What I did is I copied the .git folder to the gerrit's git repo and renamed it as xyz.git and tried to import that into eclipse. But I am not able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the *.git Directory of the git repository to the directory where gerrit deposits the git repos. After restart of gerrit should process the new project and add it to the list of new projects and you can edit description and access rights.

Comment: Actually the local git repository has folder structure myProject/.git and the git repo of gerrit directly contains demo-project.git . Its the folder structure here that creates the problem.Could you make your answer little more clear